# Dimension too large error for rectangle in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, dimensions

I have a plot of time series. Now I want to highlight certain regions using rectangles. Since the rectangle should cover the whole plot and I used enlarge limits, I tried to work around this using `rel axis` command, e.g., `({axis cs:86.27,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0})`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\cm\tothe{-1}}

\usepackage{
    pgfplots,
    filecontents
}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\small},
    every axis label/.append style={font=\large},
    every axis/.append style={line width=0.5pt},
    every major tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        major tick length=3pt, 
        %       tick align=outside, 
        black
    },
    every minor tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        minor tick length=1.5pt, 
        black
    },
    every linear axis/.append style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}},
    plot/.style={
        scale only axis=true, 
        scale=\sc, 
    },
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{peak3.txt}
    0   1620.68954  0.79213 1622.76557  0.12062
    5   1619.7955   0.34975 1619.92276  0.43016
    10  1618.04759  0.31042 1619.55825  0.287
    15  1617.88205  0.09656 1619.28215  0.61612
    20  1616.68597  0.34419 1619.18661  0.15289
    25  1616.12155  0.09647 1618.62932  0.22816
    30  1616.0003   0.06372 1617.68941  0.33931
    35  1615.57737  0.12619 1615.77222  0.56178
    40  1615.5724   0.23914 1616.20548  0.46981
    45  1615.66172  0.18898 1615.57348  0.2827
    50  1615.32729  0.06836 1615.67729  0.44124
    55  1615.46503  0.10357 1615.125    0.1919
    60  1615.52368  0.19132 1614.3899   0.35759
    65  1615.49754  0.1619  1614.90156  0.44356
    70  1615.5754   0.23436 1614.92835  0.2785
    75  1615.43131  0.15515 1614.83321  0.28528
    80  1615.48456  0.22911 1614.93878  0.2555
    85  1615.61115  0.138   1615.31617  0.29742
    90  1615.45136  0.36388 1615.12409  0.25968
    95  1615.16383  0.30691 1615.19095  0.19081
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{16cm}
    \def\widtha{9cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
            name=shift-peak3,
            plot,
            width=\widtha,
            height={\height/2-\heighta/2},
            enlargelimits={\enlarge},
            axis x line*=top,
            xtick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,
            ymin=1614,
            ymax=1624,
            ytick pos=left,
            ytick distance=2
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*,
            mark options={scale=\sc,fill=black},
            restrict x to domain=0:100,
            restrict y to domain=1614:1624,
            ]
            table[
            x index=0, 
            y index=1,
            ]{peak3.txt};
                        
            \node[font=\large,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (rel axis cs:0.975,0.975) {B};
            
            \draw[color=green,opacity=0,fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:10.37,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:16.17,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \draw[color=red,opacity=0,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:24.56,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:36.36,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \draw[color=brown,opacity=0,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:84.5,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:85.91,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \draw[color=orange,opacity=0,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:86.27,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:94.71,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When doing so, I get the error `dimensions too large`. I already tried to restrict the x and y domain, but it is not solving the problem.
Does anyone has an idea how to preceed here?

**EDIT:**
I changed the points of the rectangle, also added x labels etc.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\cm\tothe{-1}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\small},
    every axis label/.append style={font=\large},
    every axis/.append style={line width=0.5pt},
    every major tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        major tick length=3pt, 
        black
    },
    every minor tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        minor tick length=1.5pt, 
        black
    },
    every linear axis/.append style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}},
    plot/.style={
        scale only axis=true, 
        scale=\sc, 
    },
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{peak3.txt}
    0   1620.68954  0.79213 1622.76557  0.12062
    5   1619.7955   0.34975 1619.92276  0.43016
    10  1618.04759  0.31042 1619.55825  0.287
    15  1617.88205  0.09656 1619.28215  0.61612
    20  1616.68597  0.34419 1619.18661  0.15289
    25  1616.12155  0.09647 1618.62932  0.22816
    30  1616.0003   0.06372 1617.68941  0.33931
    35  1615.57737  0.12619 1615.77222  0.56178
    40  1615.5724   0.23914 1616.20548  0.46981
    45  1615.66172  0.18898 1615.57348  0.2827
    50  1615.32729  0.06836 1615.67729  0.44124
    55  1615.46503  0.10357 1615.125    0.1919
    60  1615.52368  0.19132 1614.3899   0.35759
    65  1615.49754  0.1619  1614.90156  0.44356
    70  1615.5754   0.23436 1614.92835  0.2785
    75  1615.43131  0.15515 1614.83321  0.28528
    80  1615.48456  0.22911 1614.93878  0.2555
    85  1615.61115  0.138   1615.31617  0.29742
    90  1615.45136  0.36388 1615.12409  0.25968
    95  1615.16383  0.30691 1615.19095  0.19081
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{16cm}
    \def\heighta{2cm}
    \def\widtha{9cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
            name=shift-peak3,
            plot,
            width=\widtha,
            height={\height/2-\heighta/2},
            enlargelimits={\enlarge},
            xtick pos=left,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,
            xtick distance=10,
            xlabel={1,4 Dioxane\,/\,w\%},
            ymin=1614,
            ymax=1624,
            ytick pos=left,
            ytick distance=2,
            ylabel={Peakposition\,/\,\si{\wn}},
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*,
            mark options={scale=\sc,fill=black},
            ]
            table[
            x index=0, 
            y index=1,
            ]{peak3.txt};
                        
            \node[font=\large,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (rel axis cs:0.975,0.975) {B};
            
            \draw[color=green,opacity=1,fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:10.37,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:16.17,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \draw[color=red,opacity=1,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ({rel axis cs:0.1037,0}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:0.1617,1});
%           \draw[color=red,opacity=0,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:24.56,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:36.36,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
%           \draw[color=brown,opacity=0,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:84.5,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:85.91,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
%           \draw[color=orange,opacity=0,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5] ({axis cs:86.27,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:94.71,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As yu can see in the picture, the new rectangle (red) is now not at the prior right position (green).

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with  \heighta  (which is undefined)  and \widtha?

Comment: Not really an answer, since I don't have a good fix, but your data range is a problem. If you increase the variation of y (e.g. plot from 0 to 1600) it works. It also works with `ymin = 0`. Since this is not really a fix for all data, I'm not writing this as an answer.
Additional note: I took me ten minutes to work through your "MWE", 70 % in there is not needed to replicate your problem, make it easier for the people to help you ;)

Comment: Apart the confusion with `\heighta` not defined and `\widtha`, as pointed out by John Kormylo, the main problem is linked with the syntax of the coordinates of the colored rectangles (comment theses and the error disappears). I will wrote an complet answer, but are you sure you will not have the bottom x axis displayed?

Comment: The problem comes from using `(10.37, 0)` (for example) when `ymin=1614`.  Any y value within the given range would do.  While the y value isn't actually used, it is still calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would do with `\def\height{16cm}` and the line `height={\height/2-\heighta/2},`, as `\heighta` is not defined (**Edit:** a new version of the code provided by the OP makes all clear).

I have also commented the line `restrict x to domain=...` and same for `restrict y to domain=...` as useless here (not related to the problem).

The main concern is with your strange mixed syntax:

```latex
({axis cs:10.37,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({axis cs:16.17,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
```

for displaying colored rectangles.

Using the syntax:

```latex
(rel axis cs:0.1037,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:0.1617,1);
```

the errors `dimension too large` are gone (x axis goes from 0 to 1 instead from 0 to 100, so a value as x=10.37 becomes x=0.1037, and y axis goes from 0 to 1 in the `rel axis cs` coordinate system).

**Edit:** it's not correct because there is a `enlargelimits` in the code, so x=0 in the `rel axis cs` coordinate system does not coincide with x=0 in the graph. So I replace it rather with the `axis cs` coordinate system, and the previous code becomes `(axis cs:10.37,1612) rectangle (axis cs:16.17,1626);` (I choose for the y values of the opposites points that definite the rectangle a little less and a little more than respectively the values of `ymin` and `ymax` used in the code).

Also, the package `filecontents` is obsolete with recent LaTeX kernel, so il your LaTeX distribution is rencent, you can cancel his loading and so you avoid the warning message about it.

I choose also to draw the rectangles before the experimental points, so that the experimental points are not colored by the semi-transparent rectangles.

The (updated) code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\cm\tothe{-1}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\small},
    every axis label/.append style={font=\large},
    every axis/.append style={line width=0.5pt},
    every major tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        major tick length=3pt, 
        black
    },
    every minor tick/.append style={
        line width=0.5pt, 
        minor tick length=1.5pt, 
        black
    },
    every linear axis/.append style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}},
    plot/.style={
        scale only axis=true, 
        scale=\sc, 
    },
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{peak3.txt}
    0   1620.68954  0.79213 1622.76557  0.12062
    5   1619.7955   0.34975 1619.92276  0.43016
    10  1618.04759  0.31042 1619.55825  0.287
    15  1617.88205  0.09656 1619.28215  0.61612
    20  1616.68597  0.34419 1619.18661  0.15289
    25  1616.12155  0.09647 1618.62932  0.22816
    30  1616.0003   0.06372 1617.68941  0.33931
    35  1615.57737  0.12619 1615.77222  0.56178
    40  1615.5724   0.23914 1616.20548  0.46981
    45  1615.66172  0.18898 1615.57348  0.2827
    50  1615.32729  0.06836 1615.67729  0.44124
    55  1615.46503  0.10357 1615.125    0.1919
    60  1615.52368  0.19132 1614.3899   0.35759
    65  1615.49754  0.1619  1614.90156  0.44356
    70  1615.5754   0.23436 1614.92835  0.2785
    75  1615.43131  0.15515 1614.83321  0.28528
    80  1615.48456  0.22911 1614.93878  0.2555
    85  1615.61115  0.138   1615.31617  0.29742
    90  1615.45136  0.36388 1615.12409  0.25968
    95  1615.16383  0.30691 1615.19095  0.19081
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{16cm}
    \def\heighta{2cm}
    \def\widtha{9cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
            name=shift-peak3,
            plot,
            width=\widtha,
            height={\height/2-\heighta/2},
            enlargelimits={\enlarge},
            xtick pos=left,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,
            xtick distance=10,
            xlabel={1,4 Dioxane\,/\,w\%},
            ymin=1614,
            ymax=1624,
            ytick pos=left,
            ytick distance=2,
            ylabel={Peakposition\,/\,\si{\wn}},
            ]
            
            \draw[color=green,opacity=0,fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs:10.37,1612) rectangle (axis cs:16.17,1626);
            \draw[color=red,opacity=0,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs:24.56,1612) rectangle (axis cs:36.36,1626);
            \draw[color=brown,opacity=0,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs:84.5,1612) rectangle (axis cs:85.91,1626);
            \draw[color=orange,opacity=0,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs:86.27,1612) rectangle (axis cs:94.71,1626);
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*,
            mark options={scale=\sc,fill=black},
            ]
            table[
            x index=0, 
            y index=1,
            ]{peak3.txt};
                        
            \node[font=\large,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (rel axis cs:0.975,0.975) {B};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You are right, the problem results from the mixed syntax of the cs. When I change the coordinates according to your answer, I won't get the right region (see edit in question). Is there a way to plot the rectangle without prior knowledge to plot the rectangle over the whole plot?

Comment: If we uses `\enlargelimits`,  we cannot easy use the `rel axis cs:` coordinate system, because the minimum value of x (corresponding of the abscisse of the left y axis) is not 0 but less), and the same for the maximum value of x. Good catch about this problem. I will try to find a workaround.

Comment: @Excelsior I have corrected the bad position of the colored rectangles.